# C: Process `cd ..` and other commands on server application and return feedback to client

Tags: c, linux, server, client-server

So I have got server/client application going on. So far I can communicate with the server quite well. I can get it to process `ls` command so the client gets the list of files. Here I have stumbled across a problem where I would like to type into server various commands like `cd ..`, `mv`, `cp` or `cd directory` so the server can process them and client would get a feedback on those actions. I thought that the code would go somewhere between those lines:

```
message_size = recv(socket_fd, input, sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]), 0);
if(message_size > 0) {
  /* Process incoming message, add end of the line sign */
  input[message_size] = '\0';

  /* Process command and get a response from it */
  fp = popen(input, "r");
  if(fp == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "popen() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  else {

    // IS THIS THE RIGHT APPROACH??
    if(strcmp(input, "ls") == 0) {
      while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        output[i] = c;
        i++;
      }
    i = 0;
    send_message(socket_fd, output);
   }
   else if(strcmp(input, "cd ..") == 0) {
      send_message(socket_fd, "cd ..");
   }
 }

 pclose(fp);
```

Quick explanation: `input` is what the server receives from the client. This can be `cd ..`. `send_message` is a function just to send some info to client - no big deal. `fp` is a type of `FILE *`

How can I distiguish various commands, get a feedback from them and especially - get a feedback on badly inserted command from client like `asdf`. My thought was that using `strcmp` I could do various processing on the client but for some reason my client freezes when I type `ls`.

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int socket_fd, port_number;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
  int rc;

  if(argc<2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Incorrect arguments input\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  port_number = 12345;

  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(socket_fd < 0) {
    perror("Error opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
  bcopy((char*) server->h_addr,(char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,sizeof(server->h_length));

  if(connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("Error connecting");
      exit(1);
  }

  enum {
    INIT_STATE,
    READY_STATE
  } serv_state = INIT_STATE;

  #define check_serv_state(str, st) \
   (strncmp(str, #st, sizeof(#st) - 1) == 0)

  for(;;) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    rc = recv(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if(rc<0) {
      perror("Error reading back from server");
      exit(1);
    }
    else if(rc == 0) {
      printf("The server has been disconnected. Quitting.\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    if(serv_state == INIT_STATE) {
      char *part = strtok(buffer,"\n");
      do {
    if(check_serv_state(part, READY)) {
      printf("Server is ready\n");
      serv_state = READY_STATE;
    }
    else 
      printf("Server: [[[%s]]]\n", part);
      } while((part = strtok(NULL, "\n")));

      if(serv_state != READY_STATE)
     continue;
      } else
     printf("#server: %s", buffer);

      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
      printf("#client: ");
      fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]) - 1, stdin);

      if(send(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0)
    {
      perror("Error sending message");
      exit(1);
    }
    }

  close(socket_fd);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Olaf Dietsche said it was `fgets` fault. Now I am wondering why server does not process `cd ..` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your server is sending some welcome message, the client "freezes", because it waits for input from the server

```
for (;;) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    rc = recv(socket_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

At the same time, the server is waiting for input from the client. So both are waiting for each other. That's the reason why there is no progress.

---

To fix this, you must first read input from the user, and send this input from the client to the server. E.g. move this from the end to the beginning of the loop

```
printf("#client: ");
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]) - 1, stdin);

if (send(socket_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) < 0) {
    perror("Error sending message");
    exit(1);
}
```

---

Another gotcha might be [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

Since you send the whole buffer, including the final newline, the server must check for this newline as well

```
if (strcmp(input, "ls\n") == 0) {
```

Alternatively, you may strip it before sending the request to the server

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]) - 1, stdin);
int len = strlen(buffer);
if (buffer[len - 1] == '\n') {
    buffer[len - 1] = 0;
    --len;
}

if (send(socket_fd, buffer, len, 0) < 0) {
```

---

The `cd` command is special in the sense, that it changes the directory in the calling process only. When you use [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), the command will be processed by a child process

> The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell.
>   ...
>   The command argument is a pointer to a null-terminated string containing a shell command line. *This command is passed to /bin/sh using the -c flag; interpretation, if any, is performed by the shell.*

This means, the server calls `popen`, which creates *another* process, and this other process does the `chdir`.

If you want the server process change directories, you must not use `popen`, but do [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) in the server itself.

Comment: The thing is that, if I omit ` if(strcmp(input, "ls") == 0)` code will work on `ls` command printing it with `while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)` loop. And yes, server does send welcome message. I tried your solution, it did not help.

Comment: `fgets` was the problem. I added `\n` character in both `ls` and `cd ..` commands. Right now, I have got a situation where server processes `cd ..` command but it does not go directory up. So if I do `ls` -> `cd ..` -> `ls` I get on the second time same file list as on first time using. Why is that?

Comment: Well, you check for `cd ..`, but you don't do a `cd ..`. See [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) for details.

Comment: Isn't `cd ..` processed in the same manner as `ls`? I mean, I thought `popen()` takes care of it.

Comment: Yes, this answers it pretty well.